# How to trap syntax error signal

Tags: python

I'm creating a python framework it run a set of scripts. Each script would load some common code that performs general system initialization and logging. However, I'd like to catch and process an event when a particular script has a syntax error. Yes, it is possible to use

```
except SyntaxError:
```

But then every script will have to have this code in it. 
Is there any way to make this common? Catching a signal would work, I just don't know which signal would indicate a syntax error.

The scripts are run just as any other Python scripts:

```
test_script.py -l log_file.txt
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading the set of scripts ? Can you provide a more clear explanation ?

Comment: Just run them as any other python script:
some_test.py -l log_file.txt

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's *not* possible to use that in the module since `SyntaxError` is a *compile-time* exception. You will need to create an external loader which will use `import`, `execfile()`, etc. to load and compile the code.